# Operation on inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Prove that:

$\tan^{-1}{6x-8x^3\over 1-12x^2} + \tan^{-1}{4x\over 1-4x^2} = \tan^{-1}2x$,        $|2x|<{1\over \sqrt3}$

Comment: Hint: take the tangent of both members.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $|\alpha\beta|<1$, then
$$\arctan \alpha + \arctan \beta =\arctan\frac{\alpha+\beta}{1-\alpha\beta}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use the definition of [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values),

As $-\dfrac\pi6\le\tan^{-1}(2x)\le\dfrac\pi6,$ 
$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{6x-8x^3}{1-12x^2}=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{3(2x)-(2x)^3}{1-3(2x)^2} =3\tan^{-1}(2x)$

As $-\dfrac\pi4\le\tan^{-1}(2x)\le\dfrac\pi4,$ 
$ \tan^{-1}\dfrac{4x}{1-4x^2}= \tan^{-1}\dfrac{2(2x)}{1-(2x)^2}=2\tan^{-1}(2x)$

Answer (score 0):

With some labor, you can prove more. Consider
$$
f(x)=\arctan\frac{6x-8x^3}{1-12x^2} \color{red}{-} \arctan\frac{4x}{1-4x^2}
$$
which is defined for $x\notin\{1/2,-1/2,1/\sqrt{12},-1/\sqrt{12}\}$.
Note the *minus* sign, otherwise the identity is false.

We can compute the derivative; first, the derivatives of the two fractions are, respectively,
$$
\frac{6(1+4x^2)^2}{(1-12x^2)^2},
\qquad
\frac{4(1+4x^2)}{(1-4x^2)^2}
$$
Moreover
$$
1+\left(\frac{6x-8x^3}{1-12x^2}\right)^2=
\frac{1+12x^2+48x^4+64x^6}{(1-12x^2)^2}=\frac{(1+4x^2)^3}{(1-12x^2)^2}
$$
and
$$
1+\left(\frac{4x}{1-4x^2}\right)^2=\frac{1+8x^2+16x^4}{(1-4x^2)^2}=
\frac{(1+4x^2)^2}{(1-4x^2)^2}
$$
so we have
$$
f'(x)=\frac{6}{1+4x^2}-\frac{4}{1+4x^2}=\frac{2}{1+4x^2}
$$
which is the same as the derivative of $g(x)=\arctan(2x)$. Thus we can say that
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
c_1+\arctan(2x) & x<-1/2 \\[4px]
c_2+\arctan(2x) & -1/2<x<-1/\sqrt{12} \\[4px]
c_3+\arctan(2x) & -1/\sqrt{12}<x<1/\sqrt{12} \\[4px]
c_4+\arctan(2x) & 1/\sqrt{12}<x<1/2 \\[4px]
c_5+\arctan(2x) & x>1/2
\end{cases}
$$
Since you're interested in $c_3$, just note that $f(0)=0$, so $c_3=0$.

For completeness, we can compute
$$
c_1=\pi,
\quad
c_2=\pi/2,
\quad
c_3=0,
\quad
c_4=\pi
\quad
c_5=0
$$

---

Here's a way to see that your formula is wrong:

```
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
x=1/(2*sqrt(12))
a((6*x-8*x^3)/(1-12*x^2))+a(4*x/(1-4*x^2))
1.40517450751406798853
a(2*x)
.28103490150281359770
a((6*x-8*x^3)/(1-12*x^2))-a(4*x/(1-4*x^2))
.28103490150281359773
```